# Cannot create window of class wxWindowNR

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I want to create a second independent window using C++/wxWidgets and I get an error "cannot create window of class wxWindowNR" at runtime and the second window doesn't show up. No compiler/linker errors.

The offending code is:

```
void test_gui(){
    ActorDetails *ac = new ActorDetails(wxGetApp().GetTopWindow(),wxID_ANY,wxDefaultPosition,wxDefaultSize); //ActorDetails inherits wxFrame
    wxPanel *Panel1 = new wxPanel(ac, wxNewId(), wxPoint(256,224), wxDefaultSize, wxTAB_TRAVERSAL, _T("ID_PANEL1"));
    ac->Show(true);
}
```

Any idea what's going on/going wrong?

Comment: There is nothing wrong in the code you show, so there must be something wrong in the code you do not show, namely `ActorDetails` ctor.

Answer (score 1):

I'd the same error message today. Most probably you forgot to call the wxFrame constructor from your ActorDetails constructor.

Answer (score 0):

replacing

```
ActorDetails *ac = new ActorDetails(wxGetApp().GetTopWindow(),wxID_ANY,wxDefaultPosition,wxDefaultSize);
```

with

```
ActorDetails *ac = new ActorDetails();
ac->Create(wxGetApp().GetTopWindow(), wxNewId(), _("Existenz Console"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE, _T("id"));
```

now produces a window as expected. Unfortunately I do not know what the difference is, but the second variant of code successfully instantiates and shows the second wxFrame.

This of course required the addition of a new empty constructor no parameter constructor to the class ActorDetails (not shown here).